# How to use a while loop to print every number in a range in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a practice problem that says, "Make a function that receives an integer as an argument (step) and that prints the numbers from 0 to 100 (included), but leaving step between each one.
Two versions: for loop and a while loop.

I can do it using a foor loop:

```
def function(x):
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, 100, x):
        print(x)
```

I can't seem to make it work with a while loop. I've tried this:

```
def function(x):
    count = 0
    while count <= 100:
        count += x
        print(count)
```

so please, help. Thank you!

Comment: move count+=x after print

Comment: In the `while` version, you should print before you increase the step. Also, you don't need `count = 0` in the `for` version.

Comment: True! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment `count` after printing.

```py
def function(x):
    count = 1
    while count <= 100:
        print(count)
        count += x
```

Comment: Done with `count = 0`. Thanks!